# How to reuse test code from open source project

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring

I'm writing a unit test for a custom subclass of `org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter<T>`
and I need a stub implementation of `org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage`. Looking through the Spring unit tests in the SVN repository, I found the class [MockHttpInputMessage](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web/src/test/java/org/springframework/http/MockHttpInputMessage.java), which does exactly what I want.

Now, I wonder what is the proper way to reuse this class?

Or is it generally a bad idea, because the class is not meant to be used outside of the Spring unit tests?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I wish I could accept all three of them. I chose Jens' because he mentions the license.

Comment: You can always upvote answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not involved in the Spring project, but from the names I would assume that the class is not intended for reuse. Therefore, I would simply take the class in source form and add it to your project test sources.

Of course all this assumes, this is acceptable with respect to licenses.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply copy it to my own repository, and use it to my hearts content.  You want it under your own control so that you are not adversely affected by future changes.